# How to speed up SQLAlchemy select query?

Tags: python, sql, performance, sqlalchemy

I have a table in a SQL Sever database that has approximately 50M rows and 20 columns (most of which are UUIDs, such as '26EAEDA2-85BA-0B0A-CAF8-ED671AEF7D29') (Table size is 11GB.). If I run a select query in SQL Sever it takes 6 minutes to complete. If I run the query in Python using SQLAlchemy it takes forever (I have never actually got an output unless I filter the query to only select about 1.5M rows).

Code is as follows:

```
def get_data(session):
    query = session.query(L3Moment)
    return pd.read_sql(query.statement, query.session.bind) 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine, session = create_cnx('FB')
    s = time.time()
    df = get_data(session)
    e = time.time()
    print(df)
    print(e - s)
```

PC set up:

- SQL sever on same drive as OS
- Storage is 1TB SSD
- Super fast 16 core CPU and a 16 core GPU
- 64GB of ram

TempDB files:
[TempDB files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOS1K.png)

How do I speed up the query in SQLAlchemy/Python?

I have tried comparing times in SQL Sever and Python.
I have tried filtering data to see if less columns or rows impact time.
I have inspected the database to see if any indexes are suggested (none suggested).